# How to add "usesCleartextTraffic": true, to an Expo managed project?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm supposed to add this script to the manifest file, but there is no such file in an expo managed project.

Comment: What kind of apps are people creating in which this isn't a common problem? If building in dev you clearly will need at bare minimum to accept fetch requests that use https with a self signed certificate, but they don't even allow for that. It's insane this isn't a common use case that is clearly communicated in docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Expo `app.config.js` (or equivalent json file), add:

```
   "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "usesCleartextTraffic": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
```